# How can I change the numbering of a subsection to letters?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I am reading a book whose table of contents has something like this:

> ...
>
> 2.2 Title of the Subsection
>
> 2.3 Title of the Subsection
>
> 2.3.A Title of the Subsection
>
> 2.4 Title of the Subsection
>
> ...

How can I achieve exactly that? Please note that 2.3.A is also a subsection, not a subsubsection belonging to 2.3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please explain why you need this? This is very unusual! Do you need this numbering only one time or more?

Comment: I want to write a pdf file summarizing what each subsection of the book says. So I hope my numbering could be exactly like the book. And I'd say only one time if that's easier to achieve.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [New level of section, interaction with hyperref](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/226550)

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: @Mico I am using article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you do the following:

- In the preamble, issue the intstruction

  ```
  \let\origthesubsection\thesubsection
  ```

  This instruction "saves" the default format of the subsection counter's representation
- Just before the start of subsection 2.3A, issue the following instructions:

  ```
  \renewcommand\thesubsection{\origthesubsection A}
  \addtocounter{subsection}{-1}
  ```
- Just before the start of the next, "standard-numbered" subsection, issue the instruction

  ```
  \renewcommand\thesubsection{\origthesubsection}
  ```

This approach works with the `hyperref` and `cleveref` packages, and it also lets you create a table of contents via the `\tableofcontents` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\crefname{subsection}{subsection}{subsections}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\let\origthesubsection\thesubsection

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}

\tableofcontents

\subsection{AAA}
\subsection{BBB}
\subsection{CCC}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\origthesubsection A}
\addtocounter{subsection}{-1}
\subsection{DDD} \label{sec:ddd}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\origthesubsection}
\subsection{EEE} \label{sec:eee}
\subsection{FFF} \label{sec:fff}

\ref{sec:ddd}, \ref{sec:fff}

\autoref{sec:ddd}, \autoref{sec:fff}

\cref{sec:ddd}, \cref{sec:fff}

\cref{sec:ddd,sec:fff}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It works well and is exactly what I want.